# Create and use controller for tempale in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller

I'm trying to sort out in Angular. Want to create my own modal with arbitrary template in container and controller for that template.

```
angular.module('common')
 .service('MyModalService', ['$rootScope', '$compile', 
                     function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    var service = this,
        scope;

    // params = {
    //      templateUrl: string,
    //      controller: function/array,
    //      bindings: object,
    //}
    service.show = function (params) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
        // what to do with controller?!?!?
        // how inject dependencies?
        // how bind bindings to $ctrl?
        var element = $compile('<div id="my-modal-container"><ng-include src="params.templateUrl"></ng-include></div>')(scope);
        body.append(element);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I dont think you need to do all this just to show modal, you can use ui-bootstrap for modals. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40299799/4316707 check out this answer this will give you an understanding

Comment: Are you using **$compile** bercause you what to dinamically add controls to DOM? I didn't understand that part.
Have you tried to create an angular component? check it out [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Comment: @Angular_10 ui-bootstrap is doing what i want. As well as $mdDialog of angular-matirial. But I want to understand how it works inside. Sourse code of $mdDialog was too hard for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution in $injector.instantiate() function

```
angular.module('common')
 .service('MyModalService', ['$rootScope', '$compile', '$injector', 
                      function ($rootScope, $compile, $injector) {
    var service = this,
        scope;

    // params = {
    //      templateUrl: string,
    //      controller: function/array,
    //      locals: object,
    //}
    service.show = function (params) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new(true);

        // wrap controller function in array
        if (!params.controller) {
            params.controller = [new Function];
        } else if (!Array.isArray(params.controller)) {
            params.controller = [params.controller];
        }

        var controllerFunction = params.controller.splice(params.controller.length - 1)[0];
        controllerFunction.$inject = params.controller;
        scope.$ctrl = $injector.instantiate(controllerFunction);
        angular.merge(scope.$ctrl, params.locals);
        scope.templateUrl = params.templateUrl;

        var element = $compile('<div id="my-modal-container"><ng-include src="templateUrl"></ng-include></div>')(scope);
        body.append(element);
    };
}]);
```